# Using .htaccess and authfile to protect different parts of a CGI script

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess, mercurial

I am setting up a mercurial server on my shared hosting account with bluehost. I do have ssh access but do not have access to the apache config. Basically the mercurial server runs off one single cgi script, in my case domain.com/repos/hg.cgi (for access to all repositories on the server). I have protected the "repos" directory using a .htaccess file and an auth file.

But the way mercurial works, that for example the repository "stack" is accessed like this:
domain.com/repos/hg.cgi/stack

This poses a problem, since authentication happened in the repos directory, and all users that have access to that now have access to all the repositories.

Is there a way to protect the individual repositories using just a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within each repository's `.hg/hgrc` file you can list users that can and can't access it:

```
[web]
allow_read = you,yourfriend
allow_push = you
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the localhost to access it use

```
<File "/path/to/repos/hg.cgi/stack">
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</File>
```

Comment: You could also provide a different authentication within the File tag

Comment: Can I use the <File "/path/to/repos/hg.cgi/stack"> ... </File> syntax in a .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't think that will work since /stack isn't an actual file -- it's extra path info on the file hg.cgi.  Normally you'd use a <Location> for this instead, but I don't think they're allowed in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: In a .htaccess, you can use File. I do not know about Location. I have not tried this so I am not 100% sure that File will work as Ry4an pointed out it is not technically a File.

Comment: I attempted to place Auth commands like AuthUserFile and Require valid-user for different <File></File> blocks, but it caused a 500 error. I assume it is complaining about cgi/stack not being a physical location.

Comment: try just hg.cgi and forget the /stack part

Answer (score 0):

On a shared hosting system where you have SSH access, if you are interested, you can share repositories via shared SSH using [hg-gateway](http://parametricity.net/b/2011/02/20/hg-gateway-supporting-multiple-mercurial-users-on-a-shared-ssh-account/). That way you dont have to deal with typing or saving https passwords.